# Neo4j Cypher- With clause query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm doing some codes on the Neo4j's movies dataset the question was

> Retrieve the actors who have acted in exactly five movies, returning the name of the actor, and the list of movies for that actor.

I wrote this following query and im not getting the result and it shows "no changes no result"

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH  a,m, count(m) AS numMovies
WHERE numMovies = 5
RETURN a.name,collect(m.title) AS movies
```

where as when I wrote this query for the same satement this time I just write the "collect(m.title) AS movies " in the WITH clause and I got the desired result.

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH  a, count(m) AS numMovies, collect(m.title) AS movies
WHERE numMovies = 5
RETURN a.name, movies
```

My doubt is that why result varies when I wrote the "collect(m.title) AS movies" in the RETURN clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query has `m, count(m)`, which will result in a count of 1 for each Movie node `m`.

You can check this by returning from the query in the second line:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
RETURN a, m, count(m) AS numMovies
```

The solution is to remove the separate `m` variable from the `WITH` clause as shown in your second query.